# Trigger Google Cloud Build with Google Cloud Scheduler periodically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-scheduler

Is it somehow possible to trigger a [Google Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/) with [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) periodically?

I can't find anything related to it on the Internet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Cloud Scheduler we perform a HTTP request on the project's build trigger: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/run

For authentication we use a service account.

Answer (score 14):

**The first option is to create a schedule to trigger a build:**

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create http ${PROJECT_ID}-run-trigger \
    --schedule='0 12 * * *' \
    --uri=https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/triggers/${TRIGGER_ID}:run \
    --message-body='{\"branchName\": \"${BRANCH_NAME}\"}' \
    --oauth-service-account-email=${PROJECT_ID}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
    --oauth-token-scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

Note that you can almost run this from within a cloud build. PROJECT_ID is the name of the project and BRANCH_NAME is the name of the branch (development, master, etc.). Both are available from within your cloud build pipeline. TRIGGER_ID can be fetched with the following command:

```
gcloud beta builds triggers list --format json
```

Additional to `branchName`, you can also specify other attributes in the message body, giving you more flexibility:

- commitSha
- dir
- invertRegex
- projectId
- repoName
- substitutions
- tagName

**The second option is to submit a cloudbuild on a schedule:**

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create http ${PROJECT_ID}-run-build \
    --schedule='0 12 * * *' \
    --uri=https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/builds \
    --message-body-from-file=cloudbuild.json \
    --message-body="{\"branchName\": \"${BRANCH_NAME}\"} \
    --oauth-service-account-email=${PROJECT_ID}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
    --oauth-token-scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

Your cloudbuild.json can look something like this:

```
{
    "timeout": "60s",
    "steps": [
        {
            "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud",
            "entrypoint": "bash",
            "args": [
                "-c",
                "echo "Hello"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud",
            "entrypoint": "bash",
            "args": [
                "-c",
                "echo "World"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "substitutions": {
        "BRANCH_NAME": "$BRANCH_NAME"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great but I needed to add quotes around the message body.

--message-body="{\"branchName\": \"${BRANCH_NAME}\"}"

Comment: thanks ... In my case it was --message-body='{ "branchName": "main" }'

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by making the Cloud Scheduler job target the [Cloud Build projects.builds.create API](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds/create) to [manually start your builds](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/start-build-manually). With this you can pass a [Build instance](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Build) through the request body to specify your build.

Keep in mind that you will need to authenticate your request, check the [Using authentication with HTTP Targets](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth) documentation for more information on how to do that.

Comment: A better way is probably to run an existing build trigger: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/run